# Comparing Buffer Subsets

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, buffer

**Setup:**
I have a Buffer (A) that contains multiple int64 and hence has a size that is a multiple of 8 bytes. I further have a Buffer (B) that contains a single int64.

**Problem:**
I need to determine if Buffer A contains the int64 of Buffer B. I can not use a simple "contains", since that could also match between different int64.

The best I managed so far is to slice the Buffer A into multiple int64 Buffers and then do a simple equal comparison for each piece. However this is way too slow for my use case.

**Question:**
How can I efficiently check that the int64 in Buffer B is contained in the set of int64 in Buffer A?

---

**Edit:** To clarify, I'm looking for a code example. I would like to loop through Buffer A and compare subsets of Buffers. Can you do something like that in nodejs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally went with the following solutions

```
let offset = -1;
do {
  offset = bufferA.indexOf(bufferB, offset + 1);
  if (offset % 8 === 0) {
    return true;
  }
} while (offset !== -1);
return false;
```